Symfony 7.1.4's authenticator doesn't authenticate
I'm trying to implement security form authentication in a Symfony 7.1.4 project. Nothing happens after submitting form to /login Route with POST type. No error in logs. Any idea how can i debug ?
Thanks for your help.
security.yaml:
        main:
            lazy: true
            provider: app_user_provider
            entry_point: 'form_login'
            form_login:
                login_path: app_login
                check_path: app_login
                enable_csrf: true
                failure_path: /login
                default_target_path: /
            #                target_path_parameter: dashboard
            logout:
                path: /logout

Controller:
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Attribute\Route;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\AuthenticationUtils;

class SecurityController extends AbstractController
{
    #[Route('/login', name: 'app_login')]
    public function login(AuthenticationUtils $authenticationUtils, Request $request): Response
    {

        // get the login error if there is one
        $error = $authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();

        // last username entered by the user
        $lastUsername = $authenticationUtils->getLastUsername();

        return $this->render('prehospsecurity/login.html.twig', [
            'last_username' => $lastUsername,
            'error' => $error,
        ]);
    }

    #[Route(path: '/logout', name: 'app_logout')]
    public function logout(): void
    {
        throw new \LogicException('This method can be blank - it will be intercepted by the logout key on your firewall.');
    }
}

Twig form:
{% extends '@CavansitePrehosp/base.html.twig' %}

{% block title %}Log in!{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
    <form method="post">
        {% if error %}
            <div class="alert alert-danger">{{ error.messageKey|trans(error.messageData, 'security') }}</div>
        {% endif %}

        {% if app.user %}
            <div class="mb-3">
                You are logged in as {{ app.user.userIdentifier }}, <a href="{{ path('app_logout') }}">Logout</a>
            </div>
        {% endif %}

        <h1 class="h3 mb-3 font-weight-normal">Please sign in</h1>
        <label for="username">Username</label>
        <input
                class="bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 rounded-lg focus:ring-primary-600 focus:border-primary-600 block w-full p-2.5 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:border-gray-600 dark:placeholder-gray-400 dark:text-white"
                type="text" value="{{ last_username }}" name="_username" id="username"
{#                class="form-control" #}
                autocomplete="username" required autofocus>
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input
                class="bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 rounded-lg focus:ring-primary-600 focus:border-primary-600 block w-full p-2.5 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:border-gray-600 dark:placeholder-gray-400 dark:text-white"
                type="password" name="_password" id="password"
{#                class="form-control" #}
                autocomplete="current-password" required>

        <input type="hidden" name="_csrf_token" value="{{ csrf_token('authenticate') }}">


        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" type="submit">
            Sign in
        </button>
    </form>
{% endblock %}


The code was generated with the maker bundle: bin/console make:security:form-login.

"Nothing happens" - what does that mean? What would you expect to happen? Does Symfony's profiler provide more details?

i mean Authenticator doesn't authenticate, returns login form as it was a GET request on /login Route. Profiler confirmes "Authenticated No"

"returns login form as it was a GET request on /login Route" - are you sure? Did you check your browser's network console or the profiler data about this?

Network console indicates POST.
interesting message in log: security.DEBUG: Authenticator does not support the request. {"firewall_name":"main","authenticator":"Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\FormLoginAuthenticator"}. I guess this is the problem. How could i debug this ?

just noticed an error in security.yaml config, in the access_control section.
i replaced IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY by PUBLIC_ACCESS on { path: '^/login$', role: PUBLIC_ACCESS }, which was doing an infinited loop.

infinite loop due to bad role { path: '^/login$', role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY } instead of { path: '^/login$', role: PUBLIC_ACCESS }.
Role was changed since Symfony 6, my bad :(
